# Node Access Product + UC Marketplace

Tags: ubercart, users

I want store owners to be able to offer node access to people who purchase their products.

The only problem with this, is when I give the permission "Create and edit NAP" to the developer/store owner role, it gives the permission to ALL nodes.

I've looked for a setting to change this, so that it is only for nodes who have the same author as the current logged in user, and I'm not seeing a way to do this anywhere.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a different module to accomplish this? Should I custom code something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to restrict this by modifying the module and adding a setting.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more detail on the problem and your setup. For example what is a store owner, is this just and administrator of a single site or do you have many store owners on one installation, for example some kind of marketplace?

What do you mean by node access? you want customers to buy a product and then be able to view or edit it.

What version of ubercart/drupal are you using?

If the scenario is you have only one store owner per site and you want a customer to purchase a product and then have view access to a specific node I would look into using the following modules

- node reference / entity reference - create a reference to a node from
  a product
- content access - this allows fine grained permissions for individual
  nodes or for content types etc
- Rules - create a rule that after successful checkout grants
  permission to the node that is referenced on the product

Answer (score 0):

You just need to configure the Content Access Module:

1. Download Content Access: https://drupal.org/project/Content_Access
2. Enable it
3. Edit your node content type and go to "Access Control"
4. Uncheck the user role for "View any [content_type_name]" and below that check the user role for "View own [content_type_name]" only.

And you're done.